# Chart.js Radar Not Displaying Data Values

Tags: chart.js

My Radar chart will not display the data value when hovering over a point. `Chart.js 2.8.0`

```
<script src="./vendor/chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart" width="1200" height="550"></canvas>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("radar-chart"),{
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Buisiness Loans","Residential Loans","Aggriculture Loans","Student Loans","Personal Loans"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Guthrie",
            data: [13,22,21,29,15],
            }],
    }
});
</script>
```

This still happens when I use the template [on this page](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/#4-radar-chart).
So may not be directly due to something in `chart.js`. Problem occurs both in chrome and edge. I have no additional plugins loaded and no `css`.

**EDIT 1 :** hovering will display the labels just not the data value for the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks to be a regression in 2.8.0. The two example snippets below are identical except for the version of Chart.js they use. Tooltip values are present in 2.7.2 but not in 2.8.0.

[This is apparently fixed and will be included in 2.9.0.](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6295#issuecomment-495199879)

Note you can workaround the problem with a custom tooltip callback:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("radar-chart"), {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Buisiness Loans", "Residential Loans", "Aggriculture Loans", "Student Loans", "Personal Loans"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Guthrie",
      data: [13, 22, 21, 29, 15],
    }],
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + tooltipItem.yLabel;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart" width="1200" height="550"></canvas>
```

**2.8.0; broken tooltips:**

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("radar-chart"), {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Buisiness Loans", "Residential Loans", "Aggriculture Loans", "Student Loans", "Personal Loans"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Guthrie",
      data: [13, 22, 21, 29, 15],
    }],
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart" width="1200" height="550"></canvas>
```

**2.7.2; working tooltips:**

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("radar-chart"), {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Buisiness Loans", "Residential Loans", "Aggriculture Loans", "Student Loans", "Personal Loans"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Guthrie",
      data: [13, 22, 21, 29, 15],
    }],
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart" width="1200" height="550"></canvas>
```